# How to pass Object or array with Query string in PHP

Tags: php, query-string

I am learning PHP and wondering How do i pass an array or object with query string using php ? I do google it but could not find a good answer about it.
Here what i wondering ?

http://www.example.com/abc?array('a','b','c')

http://www.example.com/abc?object("a":"a","b":"b")

Comment: This is not the efficient and the right way of passing of values. Why don't you use json_encode or paramitized values for this?

Comment: Can you please quote me an example,as i am looking for best practises.L. Herrera

Comment: First you have to show us those values you want to pass through the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is my prefer ..you can try it

```
<?php
$link = "http://www.example.com/abc?";
//try with object
// $a = new stdClass();
// $a->a = "a";
// $a->b = "b";
//try with array
$a = ["a","b","c"];
header("location:{$link}param=".json_encode($a));
```

**www.example.com/abc**

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode($_GET["param"]);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thank you,this is what i am looking for @David JorHpan